# How to play decoded in-memory PCM with Oboe properly?

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, oboe

I use [oboe](https://github.com/google/oboe) to play sounds in my ndk library, and I use [OpenSL with Android extensions](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio/opensl/opensl-for-android) to decode wav files into PCM. Decoded signed 16-bit PCM are stored in-memory (`std::forward_list<int16_t>`), and then they are sent into the oboe stream via a callback. The sound that I can hear from my phone is alike original wav file in volume level, however, 'quality' of such a sound is not -- it bursting and crackle.

I am guessing that I send PCM in audio stream in wrong order or format (sampling rate ?). How can I can use OpenSL decoding with oboe audio stream ?

---

To decode files to PCM, I use *AndroidSimpleBufferQueue* as a sink, and *AndroidFD* with *AAssetManager* as a source:

```
// Loading asset
AAsset* asset = AAssetManager_open(manager, path, AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);
off_t start, length;
int fd = AAsset_openFileDescriptor(asset, &start, &length);
AAsset_close(asset);

// Creating audio source
SLDataLocator_AndroidFD loc_fd = { SL_DATALOCATOR_ANDROIDFD, fd, start, length };
SLDataFormat_MIME format_mime = { SL_DATAFORMAT_MIME, NULL, SL_CONTAINERTYPE_UNSPECIFIED };
SLDataSource audio_source = { &loc_fd, &format_mime };

// Creating audio sink
SLDataLocator_AndroidSimpleBufferQueue loc_bq = { SL_DATALOCATOR_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE, 1 };
SLDataFormat_PCM pcm = {
    .formatType = SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM,
    .numChannels = 2,
    .samplesPerSec = SL_SAMPLINGRATE_44_1,
    .bitsPerSample = SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16,
    .containerSize = SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16,
    .channelMask = SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_LEFT | SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_RIGHT,
    .endianness = SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN
};
SLDataSink sink = { &loc_bq, &pcm };
```

And then I register callback, enqueue buffers and move PCM from buffer to storage until it's done.

*NOTE: wav audio file is also 2 channeled signed 16 bit 44.1Hz PCM*

My oboe stream configuration is the same:

```
AudioStreamBuilder builder;
builder.setChannelCount(2);
builder.setSampleRate(44100);
builder.setCallback(this);
builder.setFormat(AudioFormat::I16);
builder.setPerformanceMode(PerformanceMode::LowLatency);
builder.setSharingMode(SharingMode::Exclusive);
```

Audio rendering is working like that:

```
// Oboe stream callback
audio_engine::onAudioReady(AudioStream* self, void* audio_data, int32_t num_frames) {
    auto stream = static_cast<int16_t*>(audio_data);
    sound->render(stream, num_frames);
}

// Sound::render method
sound::render(int16_t* audio_data, int32_t num_frames) {
    auto iter = pcm_data.begin();
    std::advance(iter, cur_frame);

    const int32_t rem_size = std::min(num_frames, size - cur_frame);
    for(int32_t i = 0; i < rem_size; ++i, std::next(iter), ++cur_frame) {
        audio_data[i] += *iter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In short:** essentially, I was experiencing an underrun, because of usage of `std::forward_list` to store PCM. In such a case (using iterators to retrieve PCM), one has to use a container whose iterator implements *LegacyRandomAccessIterator* (e.g. `std::vector`).

---

I was sure that the linear complexity of methods `std::advance` and `std::next` doesn't make any difference there in my `sound::render` method. However, when I was trying to use raw pointers and pointer arithmetic (thus, constant complexity) with debugging methods that were suggested in the comments (Extracting PCM from WAV with Audacity, then loading this asset with *AAssetManager* directly into memory), I realized, that amount of "corruption" of output sound was directly proportional to the *position* argument in `std::advance(iter, position)` in render method.

So, if the amount of sound corruption was directly proportional to the complexity of `std::advance` (and also `std::next`), then I have to make the complexity constant -- by using `std::vector` as an container. And using an answer from @philburk, I got this as a working result:

```
class sound {
    private:
        const int samples_per_frame = 2; // stereo
        std::vector<int16_t> pcm_data;
        ...
    public:
        render(int16_t* audio_data, int32_t num_frames) {
            auto iter = std::next(pcm_data.begin(), cur_sample);
            const int32_t s = std::min(num_frames * samples_per_frame,
                                       total_samples - cur_sample);

            for(int32_t i = 0; i < s; ++i, std::advance(iter, 1), ++cur_sample) {
                audio_data[i] += *iter;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your render() method is confusing samples and frames.
A frame is a set of simultaneous samples.
In a stereo stream, each frame has TWO samples.

I think your iterator works on a sample basis. In other words next(iter) will advance to the next sample, not the next frame. Try this (untested) code.

```
sound::render(int16_t* audio_data, int32_t num_frames) {
    auto iter = pcm_data.begin();
    const int samples_per_frame = 2; // stereo
    std::advance(iter, cur_sample);

    const int32_t num_samples = std::min(num_frames * samples_per_frame,
              total_samples - cur_sample);
    for(int32_t i = 0; i < num_samples; ++i, std::next(iter), ++cur_sample) {
        audio_data[i] += *iter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly, this was not the case. I changed my code to respect the number of channels both in sound render and mixer render (mixer is just a proxy since I only test one sound right now) however, this does not help.

Comment: There may be more than issues than just the samples/frame problem.  If the iterator is reading from a file then there would be some serious real-time issues that would cause glitches.  Does it sound like there are very short pieces of proper sound with glitches? Or is the sound completely scrambled?

Comment: I believe it's not an I/O issue because I read the whole WAV file into the memory synchronously, and only then I render it. The sound I use is just a one-note played by an oboe, and from my phone, I hear something like that original recording, but extremely "robotized". So I guess it somehow scrambled.

Comment: You can test whether the issue is with the WAV file reader or the player. Instead of reading the WAV file using OpenSL ES, try just reading the entire file into memory using fread(). The WAV file header will sound like a noise burst. But the PCM audio after that should sound reasonable.

Or create a big array, write a sine wave into it and then play it.

Comment: Couple of comments: 1) Are you sure your stream has the properties you requested using the builder? You should check things like sample rate, channel count and format *after* you call `openStream` to verify that you actually got what you asked for. 2) As Phil says you can load the WAV file directly into memory and play it. I use Audacity->File->Export->Other uncompressed files->Header=RAW, Encoding=Signed 16-bit PCM. Example of output/use here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/musicalgame-using-oboe/index.html#4

Comment: When using raw files, it is important that the file matches the endianness of the machine. If the file is stored BigEndian and the computer is LittleEndian then it will sound very bad.

Comment: @philburk Oh, oboe doesn't enforce little endianness ? For some reason I thought it does. I'll try to load a file directly from an asset, and also I will check endianness on my phone. Thanks !

Comment: Oboe and AAudio assume the data is in the correct native format for the CPU. The data should be valid number.

If the file is different than it needs to switched when it is loaded. I think AIFF files are BigEndian and WAV files are LittleEndian.